# Can not access windows 8 drive from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, drive

I am dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu ...i finally got them both working

my problem is i can not see my windows drive from ubuntu ....i can see it listed with i open up nautilus  ...but when i click on on it i get an error and can not read it

how do i fix this ....what did i do wrong in my install that would give me a mounting error

I have another dual boot machine and that machine mounted the windows drive automatically

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

When you turn off the computer using Windows 8, the system actually hibernate, and the windows partition is marked as being used. That prevents other OSes to access the data on the partition. Try to reboot the computer (not turn off) from windows 8, enter ubuntu and access the windows partition

Comment: I am still not able to read the OS drive ...it does not give me the hibernate error msg ....I have ran into that before   The msg i know got is Adding for uid 1000 to '/media/username' failed:Operation not supported